# Сравнение строк по указанному количеству символов

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как можно сравнить строки в *C#*? К примеру, мне нужно чтобы имеющиеся строки совпадали с той, которая нужна, но не целиком, а на указанное количество символов?

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые вопросы. Приведи примеры строк которые ты считаешь равными и которые нет

Comment: `string.Contains()` ?

Comment: @Sv__t, скорее всего не подойдет если нужно, чтобы в строках совпадало только несколько символов а остальные могут не совпадать

Comment: я пробовал startswith но не понял как именно она работает... ну вот к примеру эталон для сравнения слово "привет" и есть массив "привет33434", "привииттьь","привет445" и там где к в имени присутствует "привет", неважно в середине слова или вконце тогда это подоходит как то так.

Comment: начало должно начинаться с любых букв?

Comment: "привииттьь" вот тут нет слова "привет"

Comment: Добавь эти примеры в сам вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Если именно слово `привет` (в такой последовательности) нужно найти в строке, то как раз `string.Contains("привет")` и подходит.

Comment: в цикле сравниваете каждый символ строки из набора с указанной строкой. При каждом совпадении увеличиваете счетчик. Потом просто сравниваете получившиеся значение с параметром.

Comment: ...было бы неплохо увидеть тестовые примеры

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно проверить на наличие слова `"привет"`, тогда просто `Contains()`:

```
string myString = "123привет123";
bool flag = myString.Contains("привет"); // true
```

Если же нужно проверить строку на наличие каких-либо символов, то можно так:

```
List<char> myList = "привет".ToList();
string myString = "ртиепв";
bool flag = myList.All(x => myString.Contains(x)); // true
```

Comment: Проще наверное `List<char> myList = "привет".ToList();`

Comment: @VladD, исправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

i1 - первая строка

```
var privet = i1.Substring(0, 5)
```

5 - количество символов первой строки с которыми будешь сравнивать

i2- вторая строка с которой сравниваешь

```
if (i2.StartsWith(privet )==true)
{}
```

Так будет определять содержит ли указанная строка подстроку

```
if(i2.Contains(i1) == true)
{};
```

Comment: А за что минус? Нормальный же ответ?